# Reedy model structure on sSet

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

According to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10246/model-category-structure-on-set-without-axiom-of-choice), there is a model structure on $\mathrm{Set}$ in which the cofibrations are the monomorphisms, the fibrations are maps which are either epimorphisms or have empty domain, and the weak equivalences are the maps f:X→Y such that X and Y are both empty or both nonempty.

As $\Delta^{op}$ is a Reedy category. We can consider the model structure induced on $\mathrm{Set}^{\Delta^{op}}$.
How does this model structure compare to the well known model structures of $\mathrm{sSet}$ (Quillen, Joyal)?

There is probably little hope, but can we hope a structure on $\mathrm{Set}$ which induces the Quillen model structure?

Answer (score 7):

There are only [nine possible model structures on $\mathbf{Set}$](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~oantolin/notes/modelcatsets.html). You can easily check that none of them give the right weak equivalences:

- Either everything is a weak equivalence,
- or $X \to Y$ is a weak equivalence if and only if both $X$ and $Y$ are empty or both $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty,
- or only isomorphisms are weak equivalences.

Answer (score 6):

The weak equivalences in the Reedy model structure are levelwise, and in a simplicial set if there is a simplex of any dimension then there are simplices of all dimensions.  Thus, the weak equivalences are the simplicial maps $X\to Y$ in which $X$ and $Y$ are either both empty or both nonempty; so the homotopy theory is not very interesting.